# Using xcolor package and inserting figures

Tags: floats, color

I have a report with figures. The code that I'm using is very basic and looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figures/pic}
\caption{Title}
\label{fig:name}
\end{figure}
```

Everything works fine, but as soon as I add `\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}` to my preamble, I get the following error:

```
! Too many }'s.
\color@endbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup
l.38 \end{figure}
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.
```

I haven't used xcolor in my document yet, but I plan to use it later for highlighting text. What can I do about this error?

Here's the rest of my preamble in case you need to know the details:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{jrl_thesis}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace} % this package defines the spacing of your thesis and should be included
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lma}{Lemma}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\addtolength{\voffset}{0.15in}
\addtolength{\marginparsep}{-10pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{0.25in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.75in}
```

Comment: what happens if you comment `\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}`?

Comment: If I comment, it out, everything is perfect; the document compiles and my figures show up. However, I'll need the xcolor package for later, which is why I want to include it.

Comment: I compile your code (without `jrl_thesis`) and it works, so can you edit it to be minimal

Comment: @touhami thank you for helping me pinpoint the source of my problem. `jrl_thesis` is a style file that contains a definition for `\@xfloat`. By eliminating the definition (as suggested [here](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=4766)), I got my document to work.